# Run time error for a fill in the blank ppt presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to this and I'm already facing an error.

This macro is supposed to fill color green when the answer is correct and red otherwise. I'm getting

> Run -time error '-2147188160 ( 80048240) Presentation (unknown number)
> : Invalid request. There is currently no slide show view for this
> presentation.

Please help me. Thank you!

```
Sub ReplaceColor()

    Dim CurrentSlideNo As Integer
    Dim lReplaceColor As Long
    Dim lFindColor As Long

    CurrentSlideNo = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    lReplaceColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    lFindColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)


    UCase (ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlide).Shapes("AA").OLEFormat.Object.Value)
    UCase (ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlide).Shapes("CA").TextFrame.TextRange)

    If UCase(ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlide).Shapes("AA").OLEFormat.Object.Value) =      UCase(ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlide).Shapes("CA").TextFrame.TextRange) Then
    Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lReplaceColor
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next


    Else
    Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lFindColor

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: which line produces an error and does this need to be part of an automated slideshow?

Comment: CurrentSlideNo = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
this part causes the error and this would be presented manually if i explain it right

Comment: Is the presentation in slideshow view when you run the code?  If not, you'll get that error.